# Spring boot admin with Eureka client and custom context path fails on health status

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I have configured my spring boot application `monitor-client` to register to Eureka. I have a separate spring boot admin (SBA) application `monitor` that monitors all applications registered to Eureka.

If the **context-path** is not set in my application, everything is working fine. However if the **context-path** is set, SBA does not show correct information anymore. From the documentation it seems that I need to update the metadata properties of Eureka which I have done.

My `monitor` application is configured as follows:

**application.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=monitor-client
server.servlet.context-path=/monitor-client
server.port=9876

# Monitoring config
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
eureka.instance.metadataMap.management.context-path=/monitor-client/actuator
```

My application is showing as 'offline' but I can browse all the details in the 'insight' tab. I suppose SBA correctly access the actuator endpoints but incorrectly uses the /health endpoint and I do not understand how that is possible?

If I go to the administration interface of SBA, I notice that the *wrench* endpoint and the *health* endpoint are not the same:

- localhost:9876/monitor-client/actuator (*wrench*)
- localhost:9876/actuator/health (*health*)

I've fiddled around with some settings but between the *managment* settings, the *actuator* settings and the *eureka* settings, I'm not sure which one is to be configured for this to work.

I've tried:

- management.endpoints.web.base-path
- eureka.instance.health-check-url-path

I'm currently using spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE and matching version of SBA

Comment: I am also facing this issue, have you found the resolution of it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with these configuration

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /monitor-client

#management config
eureka:
  instance:
    health-check-url-path: /actuator/health
    metadata-map:
      management.context-path: /monitor-client/actuator
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /actuator
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Comment: Why is this not marked as the correct answer?